# Force use gcc to compile (instead of cc) in ./configure under Solaris Sparc

Tags: gcc, solaris, configure, fossil

I want to build fossil code on Solaris.

```
wget http://www.fossil-scm.org/index.html/tarball/tip.tar.xz
tar xf tip.tar.xz ; cd tip.tar
./configure CC=gcc CXX=g++ C=gcc BCC=gcc  # no error
```

It will cause

```
$make
cc -o bld/translate ./src/translate.c
/usr/ucb/cc:  language optional software package not installed
$which cc
/usr/ucb/cc
$which gcc
/usr/local/bin/gcc
$which g++
/usr/local/bin/g++
```

I'm sure my gcc/g++ are workable. After I add a dirty hack on replace the 'BCC = cc' line of Makefilewith 'BCC = gcc' after ./configure.  It compilable. But I don't know how to fix the source code.

Comment: There is an infinite number of possible `configure` scripts, each with its own quirks. It is not possible to tell anything without looking at the script and/or the log it produces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I downloaded that tarball, ran command `./configure CC=gcc` and found it did not work at all, the generated `Makefile` still use `cc` for default compiler.

Use `vi` edit `Makefile`, change

```
BCC = gcc
....
TCC = gcc
```

then `make` again.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. But, I'm wonder why ./configure can not work well.

Comment: see `./configure --help` and no parameter like `CC=gcc` can be set.

Answer (score 1):

Set the compiler in the environment.

export CC=gcc