# Git installation on solaris 9

Tags: c++, c, git, gcc

i have been trying to install GIT latest version in my Solaris 9 machine where m encountering error after running 
`/usr/local/bin/make NO_OPENSSL=YesPlease  NO_CURL=YesPlease prefix=/usr all`:

```
 CC credential-store.o
```

`/usr/ucb/cc:  language optional software package not installed`

```
make: *** [credential-store.o] Error 1
```

whereas when i do `which gcc
/usr/sfw/bin/gcc`
 i get proper response 
and for 
`which cc 
/usr/ucb/cc`
In the course of installation i tried upgrading my gcc version from gcc-3.2.2 to gcc 3.4.6 but still facing the error on installation.

Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

**(1)** The compiler is not in your `PATH` variable. PATH is set to `/usr/ucb/cc` and your gcc is located in `/usr/sfw/bin/gcc`

You can either invoke the compiler using `/usr/sfw/bin/gcc` (with absolute/full path) instead of simply `gcc`

or set your PATH to

`PATH=$PATH:/usr/sfw/bin` (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-7612/customize-8/index.html)

See this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12731/usr-ucb-cc-language-optional-software-package-not-installed

To set PATH persistently see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77380/solaris-permanently-update-path-for-all-users

If PATH is set then problem is maybe that in the makefile you use the compiler is invoked with `cc` and on your machine there is no link between `gcc` and `cc`. You can try to fix this with

**(2)** create *symbolic link* between `gcc` and `cc` `ln -s /usr/sfw/bin/gcc /usr/ucb/cc` (check if link exists with `file /usr/ucb/cc` or `file /usr/sfw/bin/gcc`)
In this is more on creating and removing symbolic links https://askubuntu.com/questions/26498/choose-gcc-and-g-version

**(3)** change compiler invocation in the makefile, see this [Force use gcc to compile (instead of cc) in ./configure under Solaris Sparc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14253367/force-use-gcc-to-compile-instead-of-cc-in-configure-under-solaris-sparc)

Comment: Hello mate, Thanks for reply but i even tried in a server where path is all set with what u said.  $PATH
bash:/usr/sfw/bin:....

Comment: Can you compile if you use the full path ? Try `/usr/sfw/bin/gcc -v` (prints the configuration of gcc)